# How to solve Lower protocol stack error: 32

Tags: ios, swift4.2

I am trying to send the feedback message to the server on click of button, and am able to do that.But app is getting crashed and in console it's giving the reason as:

```
reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

as well as:

```
Lower Protocal Stack error 32
```

Could any one help me to solve this crash not to happen.

[Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpmPj.png)

Comment: You are not getting any data in `objects` array. Please check before inserting objects data for nil

Comment: you are sending white space in your parameters. that's why the issue has occurred.  when URL for post method is created it is not able to add %20 for white space (" "). please remove it then the issue gets resolved.